# Is there any way in python to find out the methods where other methods are being called?

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to write a code in pytest where it identifies the testfiles across the pytest which uses a particular method.

For Example:

```
import mathlib
 
#### Test case 1
def test_cal_square_1( ):
    result = mathlib.cal_square(5)
    assert == 25
 
 
#### Test case 2
def test_cal_square_2( ):
    result = mathlib.cal_square(6)
    assert == 36
 
 
#### Test case 3
def test_cal_cube_3( ):
    result = mathlib.cal_cube(3)
    assert == 27
 
 
#### Test case 4
def test_cal_cube_4( ):
    result = mathlib.cal_cube(2)
    assert == 8
```

So if i provide 'cal_cube' as fuunction name, it needs to list out **test_cal_cube_3** and **test_cal_cube_4**

Are there any libraries to achieve this. I have read that it can be achieved through inspect library. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Would they be able to use the `ast` module? Specifically [ast.parse](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.parse)? I was able to pass the code as a string to `ast.parse` to get an `ast.Module object`, but I don't know how to navigate it as I don't have a lot of experience with `ast`.

Comment: This sounds like something that Coverage.py could get you: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0):

I hope **inspect** library helps you. By using **getsource** function you can check if your functions' definition contains the string **"mathlib.cal_cube"**.
You may also make a list of all functions with a combination of **getmembers** and **isfunction**.

For example in your code:

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction, getsource
# it helps you to refer module from inside. If your functions are defined inside another module(file) you can simply import that module.
#(i.e. replacing sys.module with the other module's name)
import sys



def test_cal_square_1( ):
    result = mathlib.cal_square(5)
    assert result == 25
 
 
#### Test case 2
def test_cal_square_2( ):
    result = mathlib.cal_square(6)
    assert result== 36
 
 
#### Test case 3
def test_cal_cube_3( ):
    result = mathlib.cal_cube(3)
    assert result== 27
 
 
#### Test case 4
def test_cal_cube_4( ):
    result = mathlib.cal_cube(2)
    assert result== 8

# getmember finds everything defined in a module we may choose the functions (remove other definitions) with isfunction
function_list= [o for o in getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]) if isfunction(o[1])]

result_list = []
for f in function_list:
    # f is a tuple. f[0] is the name of the function in string format. f[1] is the object of function, which is the parameter of getsource function 
    f_text = getsource(f[1])
    if "mathlib.cal_cube" in f_text:
        result_list.append(f[0])
print(result_list)
```